# Struts2 variable disappearing after IF statement

Tags: java, struts2

I have this issue that is perplexing me to no end, and I have spent too much time on my own with it.  I have an IF statement and a action class variable.  Attempting to access the variable before the IF statement works fine, but attempting to access after the statement and the variable is nowhere to be found

```
<s:iterator value="groupList" var="eventMap" status="itStatus">     
    <s:property value="%{groupName}" />                         
    <s:if test="%{#eventMap.containsKey(#currTime)}">
        <s:property value="%{groupName}" />
    </s:if>
</s:iterator>
```

My Action class definitions

```
public List<AdvisorUser> getGroupName() {
    return groupName;
}

public List<Map<Integer, Event>> getGroupList() {
    return groupList;
}
```

Logically the code works great, it goes into the IF statement only when its supposed to.  Putting a debug break point on my Getter for `groupName` shows that that my getter is successfully called before the IF statement, inside the IF statement I get no breakpoint hit at all.

The keyValue for `eventMap` is an Integer and I can confirm that `#currTime` is an Integer value.  None the less, for testing I hard-coded an Integer value in its place and the same failed result.

Now with all my debugging attempts I have discovered that the issue seems to revolve around the condition in the IF statement.  If I remove the condition and explicitly put a true statement such as

```
<s:if test="%{true}">
    <s:property value="%{groupName}" />
</s:if>
```

The code works and `groupName` is called like its supposed to, everything is great!!  So using this logic I tried doing putting the true/false result of the condition into a variable and putting that variable into the IF statement like so

```
<s:set var="myResult" value="%{#eventMap.containsKey(#currTime)}"/>
<s:if test="%{#myResult}">
    <s:property value="%{groupName}" />
</s:if>
```

But of course, this does not work.  The value of `myResult` is correct every time like its supposed to, but once it enters the IF statement `groupName` ceases to exist anymore.

I am out of ideas here and have spent way too much time on something so stupid.  Can anyone please help me?  I'm curious to how simple the fix is...

**Update:**

After some more testing I found another confusion element to add to this list.  If I set the condition to enter the IF statement for FALSE instead of TRUE, then it works.

So if I enter my IF statement with a condition of `#myResult == false` my variable exists and I can access it, but when my condition is `#myResult == true` my variable is gone.

Comment: Why do you need the # before myResult ? Try removing it !

Comment: @rvraghav93 `myResult` is a local scope variable so its needs the '#' in front of it so it knows where to look.  Either way, for kicks i removed it and it didn't work.

Comment: What is `#currTime` and how do you assigning value to it? Also show how do you populate your map `Map<Integer, Event>`.

Comment: @AleksandrM `#currTime` is a counter variable from an outer loop with start and end paramters.  It is an Integer value, but possibly irrelevant because as I mentioned I have hard-coded numbers in its place for testing with the same result.

Comment: @AleksandrM The Map is populated in my action class via a loop with Key's ranging from 0 -> X.  The Keys that have an associated event get populated, the Keys with no event do not get populated in the Map.  That's why I use the `containsKey` method, to see if an event exists for that number.

Comment: @RaymondHolguin: Can you add jsp with that outer loop.

Comment: @AleksandrM `<s:iterator begin="#startTime" end="#endTime - calUtils.timeInterval" step="%{calUtils.timeInterval}" var="currTime">`

Comment: @RaymondHolguin: Try `<s:property value="#currTime.class"/>`. What does it print for you?

Comment: Its an Integer value.  That is what I meant when i said in my post that I can confirm its an Integer value, i should of clarified that.  my apologies.

Comment: @RaymondHolguin: Can you create a simple project with this error and upload it somewhere, so we can investigate this problem further.

Comment: @AleksandrM thanks for all your help, unfortunately i can't spend anymore time on this and need to move on.  I posted a work around solution for my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a work around solution for the issue.  Inside the IF statement, if I call the getter directly then it works

```
<s:property value="%{groupName}" />                         
<s:if test="%{#eventMap.containsKey(#currTime)}">
    <s:property value="%{getGroupName()}" />
</s:if>
```

No idea why i can reference the property directly above the IF statement but I can't inside, but I can't afford to spend anymore time on this and it works now.  Though if anyone can provide a better solution or explanation i would love to hear it for future reference.